# In-text citations with two or more than two papers in apacite

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

When using the parenthetical citation with two or more than two papers in `apacite`, we can separate by comma:

```
\usepackage{apacite} 

\cite{jorgenson2002projecting,solow1962technical}.
```

This gives (Jorgenson, Ho, and Stiroh, 2002; Solow,1962)

I was wondering whether there is a similar approach for using in-text citation with two or more papers:

```
\citeA{jorgenson2002projecting,solow1962technical} % two papers
\citeA{jorgenson2002projecting,solow1962technical,jones2002sources} %three papers
```

This gives `Jorgenson, Ho, and Stiroh (2002); Solow (1962)` and

```
Jorgenson, Ho, and Stiroh (2002); Solow (1962); Jones(2002)
```

but what I want is:

```
Jorgenson, Ho, and Stiroh (2002) and Solow (1962)

 Jorgenson, Ho, and Stiroh (2002), Solow (1962), and Jones(2002)




\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{paper1_bib}

Jones, C. I. (2002). Sources of US economic growth in a world of ideas. American Economic Review, 220-239.
Jorgenson, D. W., Ho, M. S., & Stiroh, K. J. (2002). Projecting productivity growth: lessons from the US growth resurgence (Vol. 20036). Washington, DC.
Solow, R. M. (1962). Technical progress, capital formation, and economic growth. The American Economic Review, 76-86.
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the apacite manual section 6.1, you need to redefine the `\BBC` command. It's default is '; ' (semicolon plus space). You simply need to redefine it to ', ' (comma plus space).

Comment: This solution always uses a comma to separate the items in a list of citations. It looks like the original poster wants ", and " before the last item when there are at least three of them in a single `\citeA`. When there are only two items the comma should be left out.